# Connect UIElements dynamically added in WPF using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have UserControl with ItemsControl binded to ObservableCollection. DataTemplate in this ItemsControl is a Grid containing TextBox and Button.

Here is some code (Updated):

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <entities:SeparatingCard x:Key="IdDataSource"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cards}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" GotFocus="TextBox_GotFocus" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <Button DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource IdDataSource}}" Command="{Binding Accept}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1">Accept</Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

In model file:

```
public ObservableCollection<SeparatingCard> Cards { get; set; }
```

Card class:

```
class SeparatingCard : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _id;
    public string Id
    {
        get { return _id; }
        set
        {
            _id = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }
    public ActionCommand Accept { get; }
    public SeparatingCard()
    {
        Accept = new ActionCommand(AcceptCommandExecute);
    }
    private void AcceptCommandExecute(object obj)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Id);
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Cards are added in runtime and I dynamically get a new textbox-button pair in my UserControl. Now in each pair I need to do the folowing things:
- Be able to check if the text in textbox is correct and disable/enable apropriate button.
- On button click get the text from apropriate textbox and process it.

I'd like all of this done via MVVM. But I only came to solution that directly have access to UI and implements only the second task:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var text = (((sender as Button).Parent as Grid).Children
            .Cast<UIElement>()
            .First(x => Grid.GetRow(x) == 0 && Grid.GetColumn(x) == 0) as TextBox).Text;
        MessageBox.Show(text);
    }
```

**Update**
As was suggested I tried to move `ICommand` logic to `SeparatingCard` class. Now it's always return null and I can't check what object of `SeparatingCard` class my command refers to. Updates are in the code above.

Comment: So, what specifically are you having trouble with? You should have a view model in your collection, with the ID value for the text. That view model will also have an `ICommand` you can bind to the `Button.Command` property. The same view model can check what is "correct" and change the `CanExecute()` value for the `ICommand` accordingly. None of this requires access to UI elements; it's all inside the view model. If you need help with all of that, please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you've tried, with a precise explanation of what you need help with.

Comment: Odd you're using the elvis operator but still not taking advantage of `nameof()` or, better yet, the [CallerMemberName](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute.aspx) attribute.

Comment: Personally I would switch to using an `ICommand` so the code to execute is in the ViewModel, however if you really want to use a `Click` method instead, you can cast the `.DataContext` of the button : `var data = ((Button)sender).DataContext as SeparatingCard;`

Comment: Maybe I miss something obvious, but I know that I can use commands and I know about `CanExecute` property. There are .xaml, .xaml.cs and model.cs files defining the `UserControl` and class for cards. How shoul I change my `DataTemplate` or classes to make it all work? The model file is a `DataContext` for .xaml file btw.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using Button.Click, Use Button.Command, which you can bind to some command in SeparatingCard.

Please have a look in this tutorial:
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/813345/Basic-MVVM-and-ICommand-Usage-Example

Then, SeparatingCard ViewModel will contain an ICommand object which you can bind to Button.Command.
So if the user clicks the button, the event will be directed to the corresponding SeparatingCard object's command.

Comment: I'm new to mvvm, but I actualy used commands in my project. I just don't get how i can bind command from button to function that will operate with its textbox.

Comment: When the user clicks the button, the command will trigger a function inside SeparatingCard. There you will able to refer to the Id field which is bounded to your TextBox.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but now `Id` property is always null. Please check code updates. May be I've made some mistakes there.

Comment: Update your xaml: TextBox Text="{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}". It updates the binding source immediately whenever the binding target property changes. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Done. `PropertyChanged` fires as intended, but nothing changed.